# How to display PHP database records in select dropdown list?

Tags: php

I created a SQL query the selects all records from a products database table. Now what I want to do is to display them in a select dropdown list.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $selectedProduct = $row['product_name'];
        }
    }
    
echo "<select>";
echo "<option value='$selectedProduct'>$selectedProduct</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add `[]` to the end of $selectedProduct where you are loading it up with rows. This tells PHP that it is an array and you are adding elements to it. Then use a `foreach` statement to create the options in the select box. You are basically looping through `$selectedProduct` to add each option. Make sure you use double quotes around the string parts, and concatenate the variable `$optionName` with periods.

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $selectedProduct[] = $row['product_name'];
            }
        }
    
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($selectedProduct as $optionName){
          echo "<option value=".$optionName.">".$optionName."</option>";
        }  
        echo "</select>";
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `<option>` inside `while` loop:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    echo "<select>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['product_name']."'>".$row['product_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Better to open another question in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is fetch all records into an array and then iterate the array displaying a new `<option>` for each element.

If you are using mysqli then you can do it like this. Fetch the ID and product name for each item. Using `fetch_all()` method put it all into an array of arrays. Then in your HTML, iterate the array and print out each option. Be careful to format the text appropriately for HTML output using `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, product_name FROM products");
$records = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo '<select name="mySelectOption">';
foreach ($records as $row) {
    echo '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($row['product_name']).'</option>';
    // or if you have an id for each option:
    echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['product_name']).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

If you are using PDO the code can be simplified a little bit.

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT id, product_name FROM products");
$records = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

echo '<select name="mySelectOption">';
foreach ($records as $id => $product_name) {
    echo '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($product_name).'</option>';
    // or if you have an id for each option:
    echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($id).'">'.htmlspecialchars($product_name).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

If you intent to submit the form with a selected value back to PHP for processing then you need to make sure that your `<select>` has a name and your `<option>` elements have a unique value. You can receive the selected value just like any other form value in PHP where the name will be the name of your select and the value will be the value chosen by the user e.g. `$_POST['mySelectOption']`.